# Access Continuous Form manipulate record order

Tags: user-interface, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to implement a `GUI` through an `Access 2007` `Form` for users to enter data through.

I am using a `continuous` style form in `Access` because the users are entering data line-by-line as they appear on a shipping invoice.

Through repeated discussions with multiple end-users and managers, it has become apparent that users will need the ability to `insert` a new record into these itemized lists if they realize that they have mistakenly skipped a line.

This means that I need to have some mechanism to manipulate the record order on-the-fly in a continuous form in `Access`. So far, I have been unable to find answers on how to do this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Important Details:**

- The lists are composed of `child` records and are each assigned a
  `detail_id`.
- The `parent` record contains a `master_id` which is associated to the
  `child` records.
- The current `order by` is `detail_id ASC`.

It would be best to not have users type the row_order they wish the final information to be entered in. I would like `Access` to either key off a separate sequence field or use an additional field in the `order by` to accomplish this.

Comment: What do you mean by 'skipped a line'? Exactly what indicates a line is 'skipped'? If this is an auto-number field, gaps should not be a concern. Autonumber ID should not have meaning to users, it's just a mechanism to link records. Don't even display the autonumber.

Comment: Okay, read question again. It is not autonumber gap that is issue - it is that you want the records to have same order as listed in the shipping invoice. I expect this will need another field for input of order sequence identifier. And if an item must be inserted this means editing all the following records if they were originally entered without a sequence gap. Is there an item number on the shipping invoice?

Comment: Yes, but the item number on the invoice doesn't appear on the report. Instead, the item description is used (which is apparently unique enough). Mhm I know that I will need an additional field to determine the record sequence. My hope was to allow users to push a button once and I could manipulate everything on the back-end. That would be preferable to having them enter a sequence order for the entire report, since they are likely to make an error.

Comment: Attempting Gustav's code fix in the mean time.